# Difference between Join and Subquery in SQL Server 2017

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

This is my first query:

```
select 
    r.[ProductID], [Name],
    [Color], [UnitPrice] 
from 
    [Production].[Product] r  
inner join 
    [Sales].[SalesOrderDetail] d on d.productid = r.productid
```

This is my second query:

```
select [ProductID], [Name], [color] 
from [Production].[Product] o 
where [ProductID] in (select [UnitPrice] 
                      from [Sales].[SalesOrderDetail] s
                      where s.ProductID = o.ProductID)
```

The first query returns correctly what I want to achieve, but the second query returns null. I want to use the second query to have the same result. Is that possible?

Comment: You are comparing `ProductD` against `UnitPrice` for second query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `exists` :

```
select p.*
from product p
where exists (select 1 from SalesOrderDetail sd where sd.productid = p.product);
```

Your second query is not same as first query. It is comparing `ProductID` against `UnitPrice` which is invalid. Should produce no result.

For original version of query you can just change the sub query unit price with `Productid` :

```
where [ProductID] in (select sd.productid from SalesOrderDetail sd)
```

However, if you want `unitprice` (which is available in SalesOrderDetail) then this subquery will not help you. You need `JOIN` instead.